# Connection between 2 or more workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

A simple questions

Is there any way to connect a sheet from the data workbook to one master workbook with the capability to change if either the sheet from the data workbook or the master workbook is changed?

If for example, I change the connected sheet A1 on the master workbook to "88" then A1 on the data workbook also becomes "88". Tried the connection function but I need to manually click the function to add the table.

also, is there any way to change paste as hyperlink to become string so I can use it for my vlookup function? because when I paste special it as hyperlink, the excel read it as link path to the origin of the file instead of the word

I use excel 2010 and it doesn't support power query

Comment: Re: hyperlink, you can either paste as a link and keep the address or you can just paste as text but lose the hyperlink property. Instead, keep the hyperlink but change the lookup value in the `vlookup()` to be `LEFT(A1, LEN(A1))` rather than just `A1`.

Comment: @bugdrown so I just change the lookup property as you suggested and the lookup will search the pasted hyperlink text?

Comment: For example, `VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,LENA1)),...)` will look up the the full text of A1, rather than trying to look up the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook.
2. In the Excel Browse dialog box, browse for or type a path to the file that you want to query.
3. Select Open.

---

###### Source: [Import data from data sources (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, my excel is 2010 version so it doesn't support power query (and my 2010 its not the premium so I can't install the power query add ons)
is there any other method that I can do similar to power query?
thank you